How to find the colored circles in an image using using python
I want to analyze an image containing multiple circles of various colors and provide a count of all the colored circles present in the image.
Following is the script and image I am using, but not getting desired result.

Note: I want to find the count of big circles only not small circles on the left top of circles that you can see in the picture
import cv2
import numpy as np

def count_colored_circles(image_path):
    # Load image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print("Error: Unable to load image.")
        return

    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise and improve circle detection
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Detect circles
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=1,
                               param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=40)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        counts = {'red': 0, 'blue': 0, 'green': 0}
        for circle in circles[0, :]:
            # Extract region of interest (ROI) for each circle
            x, y, radius = circle
            roi = image[max(0, y-radius):min(y+radius, image.shape[0]), max(0, x-radius):min(x+radius, image.shape[1])]
            # Calculate the average color in the ROI
            avg_color = np.mean(roi, axis=(0, 1))
            # Determine the color category based on the average color
            if avg_color[2] > avg_color[0] and avg_color[2] > avg_color[1]:
                color = 'red'
            elif avg_color[0] > avg_color[1] and avg_color[0] > avg_color[2]:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'green'
            # Increment count for the detected color
            counts[color] += 1

        # Print counts of each color
        print("Counts of each color:")
        for color, count in counts.items():
            print(f"{color}: {count}")

        # Visualize detected circles (optional)
        for circle in circles[0, :]:
            x, y, radius = circle
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Detected Circles', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print("No circles detected.")

# Provide the absolute path to the image file
image_path = "D:/TBL9.PNG"  # Replace "your_image.jpg" with the actual image filename
count_colored_circles(image_path)

Following is the result with image:
Counts of each color:
red: 15
blue: 10
green: 1



Please edit your post to correct the beginning of your code to include that in your formatting.  Also please do use such large bold headers or formatting. It looks like a mistake in formatting.  You might be better finding one color set of circles at a time from  the red, green and blue channels.

Hough is the problem.

Are the circles in all of the input images the same colors as these? Is the scale the same for all of them (same size circles/grids)?

Using your original image, I tuned the parameters of cv2.HoughCircles() and was able to detect all of the circles. I found you technique of identifying color interesting. Rest of the code I kept the same as yours. Please find code below.
minDist is 'Minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles', since you kept it one caused duplicate detections. minRadius and maxRadius were set analyzing the original image, if set large or small than the actual radius can cause false or miss detection.
import cv2
import numpy as np

def count_colored_circles(image_path):
    # Load image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print("Error: Unable to load image.")
        return

    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise and improve circle detection
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Detect circles
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=2, minDist=10,param1=100, param2=50, minRadius=8, maxRadius=15)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        counts = {'red': 0, 'blue': 0, 'green': 0}
        for circle in circles[0, :]:
            # Extract region of interest (ROI) for each circle
            x, y, radius = circle
            roi = image[max(0, y-radius):min(y+radius, image.shape[0]), max(0, x-radius):min(x+radius, image.shape[1])]
            # Calculate the average color in the ROI
            avg_color = np.mean(roi, axis=(0, 1))
            # Determine the color category based on the average color
            if avg_color[2] > avg_color[0] and avg_color[2] > avg_color[1]:
                color = 'red'
            elif avg_color[0] > avg_color[1] and avg_color[0] > avg_color[2]:
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color = 'green'
            # Increment count for the detected color
            counts[color] += 1

        # Print counts of each color
        print("Counts of each color:")
        for color, count in counts.items():
            print(f"{color}: {count}")

        # Visualize detected circles (optional)
        for circle in circles[0, :]:
            x, y, radius = circle
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Detected Circles', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print("No circles detected.")

# Provide the absolute path to the image file
image_path = "D:/TBL9.PNG"  # Replace "your_image.jpg" with the actual image filename
count_colored_circles(image_path)


output
red: 28
blue: 30
green: 6


